# simple "if, else" statement issues

Tags: php, javascript

I'm confused as to why this isn't show any of the pictures in the "divPIC" div.  I've tested the "rate" variable and it does indeed display a number.  Basically, this should just show a star rating picture if the rating is within the if, else statement.  Nothing shows up though.

Javascript:

```
 var rate = <?php echo json_encode($rate); ?>;

 if (rate == 0) {
    document.getElementById('divPIC').innerHTML = "<img src='images/0star.png'>";
    }
    else if (0 < rate && 4 > rate) {
    document.getElementById('divPIC').innerHTML = "<img src='images/1star.png'>";
    }
    else if (3 < rate && 6 > rate) {
    document.getElementById('divPIC').innerHTML = "<img src='images/2star.png'>";
    }
    else if (5 < rate) {
    document.getElementById('divPIC').innerHTML = "<img src='images/3star.png'>";
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divPIC"></div>
```

Comment: log rate to the console

Comment: yes, what is the value of rate?

Comment: Do you mean `<div id="PIC"></div>`?

Comment: Have you debugged to see if you are getting inside any of the if/else if blocks?

Comment: `<divPIC></div>` is invalid HTML...

Comment: Your ranges overlap - what do you really want to be shown when rate is 5?  The fact that you are `json_encode()`ing `$rate` suggests you might not be dealing with an integer value which means none of your conditions are being met.  If you have an object or string any comparison with a number will always be false.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething: The if/else statements are a bit cryptic, but if you read them, they work the way they're supposed to. The second `if` is for 1 to 3, the third is for 4 to 5, and so on. Notice he's using `<` and `>`, not `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: so I still can't figure this out.  It doesn't have anything to do with my javascript because I put alerts in each of them and they alerts pop up where they should.  The issue seems to be with the HTML....  I don't get it, I've done this before with no problems...

Answer (score 4):

```
<divPIC></div>
```

This should be changed to:

```
<div id="divPIC"></div>
```

Because you're trying to access it by its id (`getElementById`), not by its node name.

### Edit

Additionally, instead of using this:

```
var rate = <?php echo json_encode($rate); ?>;
```

You might consider this:

```
var rate = <?php echo intval($rate); ?>;
```

If `$rate` is not an integer, you'll get something nasty from `json_encode`. Instead, [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) will always return an integer.

*Edit again: Just noticed igasparetto beat me to the `$rate` suggestion. Thanks!*

Comment: I would also change `json_encode` to `intval` as he is expecting to have an integer.

Comment: sorry I fixed the question, I jsut typed the question wrong. it is <div id="divPIC">

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to write it like:

```
var r = <?php echo json_encode($rate); ?>;
if(r<1){ //show 0star img}
else if (r<4){ //show 1star img}
else if (r<6){ //show 2star img}
else{ //show 3star img}
```

That way you are handling less than zero & zero.  There is no reason to test if you are greater than the previous limit.

If you are not against jquery...

```
var $divImg = $('#divImg'); 
// do this before the if else
//then you can append
$divImg.append('<img src="thestarimg.png"/>');
```

Try this fiddle, I am just using text.
http://jsfiddle.net/VgKaN/